# reviewboard post-review and "A +" status files

Tags: svn, diff, review-board

I have some "A  +" status files after merge from another branch in my svn work path,
like this:

```
M      .
A  +    protected/extensions/Everyman/neo4jphp.phar
A  +    protected/extensions/Everyman/InitNeo4j.php
A  +    protected/extensions/Everyman/README
```

When I submit a review by using post-review, upload diff failed:

```
Error uploading diff

Your review request still exists, but the diff is not attached.
```

and the debug log show

> > > Got API Error 219 (HTTP code 400): The specified diff file is empty

when i try get diff to upload using svn diff, bug get nothing

How can I post a review for these "A  +" status files?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the diff you are trying to submit is indeed empty.

You can try "svn diff" in the folder with the files of A+ status, these A+ files are ignored.

As far as I know, there is no good way to make the "svn diff" notice the A+ files. You can however just copy the files here and use "svn add" before submitting the review, You will get the some content on the reviewboard eventually anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should create your diff file in the **unified format** - please see the reviewboard documentation that explains it [here](http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/1.6/users/review-requests/creating/#review-requests-for-diffs).

On the other hand, the ["svn diff" command](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Subversion) should give you by default the unified format but in your case it doesn't.
In this case, I would say it worth checking your SVN client documentation on how to get the unified diff format.

HTH!